# Visual Studio code extension - Getting active tab data for non-textual files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an extension in which I query the source path of the current active tab file.

For textual files, the following works great:

```
const activeEditor: TextEditor = window.activeTextEditor;
if (activeEditor && activeEditor.document && activeEditor.document.fileName) {
    return activeEditor.document.fileName;
}
```

Problem is, this doesn't work when the active file in the text editor is non-textual, for example an image file such as a `.jpg`.

For these types of files, `window.activeTextEditor` is `undefined`. Moreover, when I try running the following code:

```
const uri = Uri.file(<path_to_binary_file>);
workspace.openTextDocument(uri);
```

I receive the following error: `"cannot open <path_to_file>. Detail: File seems to be binary and cannot be opened as text"`, and I don't see any similar API to `openTextDocument` that deals with non-textual files.

Is there any straightforward way of obtaining this data without using `commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.files.copyPathOfActiveFile')` and various clipboard manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a known open issue in VS code.
The [following Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2582) discusses it.